# Is there a way to reference another cell in a range while iterating through a FOR EACH loop in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to construct a program that takes a spreadsheet with many different structured blocks of cells, searches for an empty one of these blocks and shifts all the following blocks down to fill the empty space without disturbing the order. I created a range of non-contiguous cells that each represent one of these blocks, I'm attempting to iterate through the cells of this range with a For Each loop while also referencing and checking the next cell in the range to ensure that the empty block is not at the end of the values within the range. To call this 'nextCell' in the range, I used an index variable that increments at the end of each For loop. The issue that I'm running into is that in the non-contiguous range, calling ran.Cells(i) is indexing out of the range moving to the cells directly below the current cell rather than moving to the next cell in the range. Is there any better way to do this effectively? Also I'm fairly new to VBA so I apologize for any messy code. Thanks in advance.

```
Public Sub ShiftCells()
    Dim ran As Range, cell As Range, nextCell As Range
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Flight Board - Page 1")
    Set ran = sht1.Range("C3,G3,K3,O3,S3,W3,AA3,AE3,C13,G13,K13,O13,S13,W13,AA13,AE13,C23,G23,K23,O23,S23,W23,AA23,AE23,C33,G33,K33,O33,S33,W33,AA33,AE33")
    i = 2

    For Each cell In ran

        Set nextCell = ran.Cells(i)

        'if cell is empty while next cell is not empty select and copy current cell
        If cell.Value = Empty And nextCell.Value <> Empty Then
            Range(nextCell, nextCell.Offset(7, 0)).Copy
            cell.PasteSpecial
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(7, 0)).ClearContents
        Else
        End If

        'increment index
        i = i + 1

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this with `For Each`? You can use a mix of `For Next` loops and it will be easier to reference 'out-of-range'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dean mentioned, it would be easier to use nested `For Next` loops.

Judging from the Results, I don't think your code is doing what you want it to do.

### Markers

[image: Before Image]

### Results

[image: After Image]

### Test

```
Public Function wsFlightBoardPage1() As Worksheet
    Set wsFlightBoardPage1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flight Board - Page 1")
End Function

Public Sub ShiftCells()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim Target As Range, Source As Range
    
    With wsFlightBoardPage1
        For r = 3 To 33 Step 10
            For c = 3 To 31 Step 4
                Set Target = .Cells(r, c)
                Set Source = Target.Offset(1).Resize(7)
                If Len(Target.Value) = 0 And Len(Source.Cells(1, 1).Value) > 0 Then
                    Source.Copy Destination:=Target
                    Target.Resize(7).ClearContents
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub AddMarkers()
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Count As Long
    Dim Target As Range, Source As Range
    
    With wsFlightBoardPage1
        For r = 3 To 33 Step 10
            For c = 3 To 31 Step 4
                Set Target = .Cells(r, c)
                Set Source = Target.Offset(1).Resize(7)
                Target.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Source.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Source.Value = 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

For the low low price of $0, you can download [RubberDuck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) and take advantage of it's many great features such as code formatting. After you get the Duck, you should watch this series: [WiseOwlTutorials  VBA](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&index=1&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

Comment: This is definitely much closer to the implementation I was going for. Thank you